# angular js - Not getting last inserted record in $routeChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using **$routeChangeStart** to redirect authorized users to the particular urls, and prevent the Users from special urls.

Also I have some dynamically generated pages, which I want to visit that page by page-slug.
So I am calling $routeChangeStart and on this event I am calling a **$http** service which get all page slugs from database and allow user to redirect towards it.

What happening, when I am adding new page from my backend and try to view it, the page-slug is not retrieve for last inserted page record from database, and by default the route took me to the homepage.

When I complete refresh the application (F5), then the route will found.

My sample code is here.

My Route for page :

```
$routeProvider.when('/:pageSlug',{ templateUrl:BASE_URL+'singlePage', controller:"pageController"});
```

My $routeChangeStart :

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, loginService, PageUrlService, $route)
{
    var $promise = PageUrlService.getPageUrls();

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){

        var pageRoutes = [],
            after = [],
            before = [],
            right = [],
            general = [];


        $promise.then(function(res){
            var data = res.data;

            if(data.status == "found"){
                angular.forEach(data.content, function(value, key){
                    pageRoutes.push("/"+ value.pageUrl);
                });
            }           

            if($rootScope.isLoggedIn == true)
            {
                 // route allow if found in "pageRoutes"
            }
            else
            {
                 // route allow if found in "pageRoutes"
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.run is called one time on its life cycle.

That's why the below code is executed one time.
 var $promise = PageUrlService.getPageUrls();

Put the above code inside routeChangeStart.